# Obtaining HREF with Python BeautifulSoup (BS4) with no apparent tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the URL from this HTML code subset. Basically, I found all `<item>` tags using `soup.find_all('item', class_="sale-item")` and would like to extract the URL from the first href. Can anyone assist?

```
<item class="sale-item" style="margin:6px; padding: 0; text-decoration:none;" tabindex="0" title="">
<style="text-decoration:none; display:block"="" height:100%;="" href="http://www.assus.com/12165456ALPHA.html">
<header>
<div class="smaht-header" style="width:100%; color:#000000; background-color:#EEEEEE;"><span style="color:#2a6293!important">ONLINE-ONLY</span></div>
<div style="color:#2a6293; width:100%; float:left">
....code continues to </item>
```

A lot of the BS4 solutions assume the href is encapsulated in the `a` tag. I'm unsure how to proceed with this setup...thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not use a regex? for example
https://regex101.com/r/8Ks47b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a list (`item_links` below) of all the first `href`s from inside `item` tags [that have any], you can use [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) (with [CSS selectors](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#selector)) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
item_links = [i.find(href=True)['href'] for i in soup.select('item.sale-item:has([href])')]
```

---

If you want to loop through `item`s and do more things than just getting links, you can use a `for` loop like:

```py
for item in soup.select('item.sale-item:has([href])'):
    item_link = item.find(href=True)['href'] # item.select_one('[href]')['href']
    ## WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH item AND item_link ##
```

---

If you want to loop through `item`s regardless of whether they contain any Tags with `href`:

```py
for item in soup.find_all('item', class_="sale-item"): # soup.select('item.sale-item'):
    item_link = item.find(href=True) ## no Tags with href in item --> item_link=None
    if item_link: item_link = item_link['href']
    ## WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WITH item AND item_link ##
```

---

These will find the first `href`s no matter the kind of Tag the attribute belongs to.

Comment: Thank you! This is why I ask as I'm thinking I haven't begun scratching what can really be done w BS4. Documentation is great and all but somehow I miss it. Thanks for your help again!